# AWS educate Ec2 public key error after 1-2 weeks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been using AWS educate for an ec2 instance that I connect using terminal on my macbook pro Catalina. I use ubuntu to connect (I have putty running on terminal) and I have been able to connect perfectly fine and changed nothing, but after about a week or 2 when I use the command

`sophiadhanani$ ssh -i "name of pem file.pem" ubuntu@ec2-IPnumbers.compute-1.amazonaws.com` it returns `permission denied (publickey)`.

No idea why this is happening and the trouble shoot says to create a temp instance and then mount point- is there an easier way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have not modified the `authorized_keys` file on your SSH instance and that your SSH key has permissions `400` on your macbook?

Comment: Tried 400 and it did not work and I have not changed anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an encrypted home directory on your Macbook?

Apparently, using an encrypted home, you can experience login problems.

You may want to remove the file from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to somewhere else e.g. `/etc/ssh/.authorized_keys`

And then edit your the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and add /edit to point to the new location.

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys
```